# I am trying open an audio stream from url inside android app?

Tags: java, audio-streaming, android-studio-3.4

I need to link actively streaming audio inside my app so that it plays from inside my app.

When my webView approach did not work and I could not find a working solution here, I broadened my scope and found another method (https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/08/android-play-audio-from-url-http.html) but it did not work. So I've gone back to the webView method and have included all applicable code below.

activity's java file

```
package com.app.sega;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class wvop extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webview_v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wvop);

        webview_v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_wvop);
        webview_v.setInitialScale(1);
        webview_v.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient_v());
        webview_v.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
        webview_v.getSettings().getLoadWithOverviewMode();
        webview_v.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview_v.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview_v.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview_v.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webview_v.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webview_v.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview_v.getSettings().getBuiltInZoomControls();
        webview_v.getSettings().getUseWideViewPort();
        webview_v.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview_v.getSettings().setUserAgentString("silly_that_i_have_to_do_this");
        webview_v.loadUrl("https://us7.maindigitalstream.com/2782/");
    }

    private class WebViewClient_v extends WebViewClient {

        public boolean shouldOverrideURLLoading (WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("https://us7.maindigitalstream.com/2782/")) {
                return false;
            }else {
                Intent intent_wvop = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent_wvop);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity's xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview_wvop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.app.sega">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="andoir.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="andoir.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="andoir.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="andoir.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
            android:name=".facebook"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".twitter"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".wyum"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".wtcq"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".wvop"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".sega"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.sega" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.wvop" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.wtcq" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.wyum" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.twitter" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.facebook" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I expected the app to load the url in the webview like it does any other url. This url/website has a button to open the stream, but by default the page automatically opens the stream and begins playing the streaming audio when loaded in any browser. The problem: Although I can get the page to load in the app's webview, it will not open and play the active stream. Instead I get a red error message saying, "ERROR OCCURRED This player does not work without javascript!" and this message has a semi-transparent background where I can see the page behind it. So the app is loading the page but not the appropriate javascript it seems. So that is exactly what I get with exactly the code shown above. Now what happens when I enable javascript...

In an attempt to enable javascript to fix this error message by adding "true" to this line like so..."webview_v.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled(true);" I get the following logCat error when I attempt to run the app on any device, actual or emulated.

```
error: method getJavaScriptEnabled in class WebSettings cannot be applied to given types;
        webview_v.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                               ^
  required: no arguments
  found: boolean
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Where am I going wrong in my scripts above? What should I add, remove, change, etc. 
If this webview method will not work or simply is not designed to work with such sites, then what about this method (https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/08/android-play-audio-from-url-http.html)? It was causing my app to crash, slip to the background without exiting, and throw this error message up; "Unfortunately, 'App Name' has stopped". I'd use it if it'd work but I can't figure out what was going wrong with it either.

I can feel my hair getting thinner and thinner as I pull and pull my hair out trying to figure this out.

Comment: you probably want to use `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`

Comment: @Jannik - Do you see something wrong with the way I enabled it in here?  Because I keep getting an error message when I do that.  
     "webview_v.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled(true);" 

LogCat error: method getJavaScriptEnabled in class WebSettings cannot be applied to given types;
        webview_v.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                               ^
  required: no arguments
  found: boolean
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: You have written **get**JavaScriptEnabled(true) but the actual function you must call is named **set**JavaScriptEnabled(true)

Comment: The get variant returns the current value and takes no parameter while the set variant actually changes the settings value.

Comment: In posting my last comment @Jannik I found my error when comparing my paste with your entry right above, lol.  It should read .setJavaScriptEnabled(true); not .getJavaScriptEnabled(true); I put 'get' instead of 'set'. One letter creating that much havoc in my head, smh.

Comment: Apparently you saw it the same time I did, lol. Thanks a million @Jannik.

Comment: Okay, url loads and the player seems to be running showing a time lapse status, but it still is not playing the sound. New topic...

Comment: Hm, I am no expert for the WebView, so i cannot tell where this goes wrong. There are some similar questions here on SO, but they all propose to catch the loading call of the webview and then serving the media elements with the MediaPlayer class. As far as I can tell, that's what you tried to accomplish in the first place, so its no real help. On the other hand, I've taken a short look at the blog post you linked to and for me it seems like a reasonable approach. I would recommend to create the exact sample they are providing and then post another question if some issues arise. Good luck.